# Iterate through two different arrays in the same ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have to iterate through two different arrays containing member details in one array and a approval pending members in another array. I have to display the details in a table. This is the code.

```
<div class="member-table-body" ng-repeat="member in members ">
 <div class="member-table-content s-no">1</div>
 <div class="member-table-content approved">Approved</div>
 <div class="member-table-content">{{member.firstName}}</div>
 <div class="member-table-content">{{member.lastName}}</div>
 <div class="member-table-content email">{{member.emailId}}</div>
</div>

<div class="member-table-body" ng-repeat="member in pendingRequests">
 <div class="member-table-content s-no">1</div>
 <div class="member-table-content pending">Pending</div>
 <div class="member-table-content">{{member.firstName}}</div>
 <div class="member-table-content">{{member.lastName}}</div>
 <div class="member-table-content email">{{member.emailId}}</div>
</div>
```

How to iterate through both members and pendingRequests within a single ng-repeat. Also the approved must be in the beginning of the table followed by the pending requests details.

Thanks!

Comment: if they have the same length, you can use the array directly as `pendingRequests[$index].firstName`, which will use the index of the first array. Otherwise merge them in your controller and iterate over a new array

Comment: Thanks a lot. @AlekseySolovey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concate two arrays in the controller and use it.

**JS::**

```
var members = ["a", "b", "c"]; 
var pendingRequests = [1, 2, 3];

var newMembers = members.concat(pendingRequests);
```

**VIEW::**

```
<div class="member-table-body" ng-repeat="member in newMembers ">
   //code
</div>
```

Let me know if you are facing any problem?

Comment: Thanks. I have same code in application. I reverted and applied your solution. It really helpful.

Comment: @Hareini Sreethi Is this working for you? If yes then please accept answer.